# How to add validation or input mask in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, input-mask

Is there a way to set an input mask or validation rule in MS Access 2016 so that certain elements are optional?

Employee Reference can be in a number of formats: starts with a character `E` follow by space and 10 numbers.  These will be mandatory and then the last character should be optional.

So, is there a way for me to set the input mask so that the first letter, space and 10 numbers are mandatory and last character is optional?

For example:

```
E <space> 100234240 <optional Letter>

E 100234240A 
or
E 100234240
```

Comment: Have you even researched this topic? Yes, characters can be optional. https://sourcedaddy.com/ms-access/defining-input-masks.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [official documentation](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/control-data-entry-formats-with-input-masks-e125997a-7791-49e5-8672-4a47832de8da#characters), you will require the following input mask characters to achieve your desired result:

- `0` User must enter a digit (0 to 9).
- `a` User can enter a letter or a digit.
- `""` Characters enclosed in double quotation marks will be displayed literally.

You may also wish to use:

- `>` Converts all characters that follow to uppercase.

---

Given the above, I might suggest the following input mask:

```
>"E "0000000000a;0
```

Here, the `0` following the semi-colon in the input mask indicates that the mask characters will be stored along with the data (i.e. the `"E "` will also be stored).

And if you want a different placeholder character, perhaps something like:

```
>"E "0000000000a;0;#
```

Comment: thxs Lee Mac tht work.  :) I was doing like  "E "0000000000;0;

Comment: Hi , if i use the "E "0000000000a;0;# is there a specific amendment that i need to do to below code to chk if EmployeeCode already exists ......  If IsNull(DLookup("[EmplCode]", _
"employee", _
"[EmplCode] = """ & Me.Empl_Code.Text & """")) = False Then
Cancel = True
MsgBox "Employee already exists", vbOKOnly, "Warning"
Me![EmplCode].Undo
End If
Since its allowing input & save.. Any idea??

Comment: @net This belongs as a new question and shouldn't be answered in the comments.